# How to avoid creating a session on a particular Express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use ExpressJS for an app framework, along with connect-memcached for managing Express sessions.

```
app.use( express.session({
 secret: "blah blah",
 store: new MemcachedStore({ ... })
}));
```

It works great.  Except...

I have a particular route that a number of scripts use to check that status of the app:

```
app.get( "/checkstatus", function( req, res ){
  ...
});
```

Because these are scripts that are doing the checking, everytime they check a new session gets created.  I would prefer to avoid this.

So my question is, for this particular route, how can I prevent the session from being automatically created when a request is made to it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

```
app.get( "/checkstatus", function( req, res ){
  ...
});
```

is before

```
app.use( express.session({
 secret: "blah blah",
 store: new MemcachedStore({ ... })
}));
```

in your code.

Comment: I tried this and it actually threw an error for me with passport, which I also use.  However I was able to get it working in the end by putting an app.use( "/checkstatus", stuff ) before the session middleware, and then just not calling next, which someone else on here suggested.